# Intersections of geodesics in an "almost flat" plane

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, geodesics

Let $g$ be a complete metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, such that:

- Outside of a compact connected set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, the curvature of $g$ vanishes.
- The integral of the Gaussian curvature in $K$ is zero.

Let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ be two complete geodesics in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus K$. Is it true that:

1. If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are not parallel, they intersect?
2. If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are parallel, the distance between any $p\in \gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ is bounded?

Note that by the Gauss–Bonnet theorem, it follows that in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus K$ the holonomy is trivial, and thus parallel transport is path independent, and the notion of geodesics being parallel to each other is well-defined.

Comment: You need to assume that K is connected. Then both points are true. The complement of the convex hull of K is isometric to a holed euclidean plane cut up along a ray and glued back with some shift along the cut.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev 
Thanks, I meant that  is connected, and edited it in the question. Indeed, my aim is to show that it is isometric to the cut-shift-glue procedure that you describe. But (1) is it known that the convex hull of  is compact? and (2) how do you show that this cut-shift-glue procedure yields an isometry and not just an isometric immersion?

Comment: Could you make answer from your comment, so the question will be removed from unanswered list?